Is datetime.strptime safe with untrusted inputs?
Pretty much the title. I want to use datetime.strptime in my flask application with dates I am getting over post requests.
Can I directly feed the input to strptime and catch exceptions and that should be enough security-wise? Should I do any more validation before?

strptime mostly/partly delegates to lower level system libraries, which are also used by a ton of other code. While nobody can be entirely certain there won't be an exploit discovered some day, I think so far the track record and fairly reassuring, seeing as systems aren't being exploited left and right with simple time strings…

that sounds reassuring. So I understand that the practice is to use it with untrusted inputs directly?
